# Can we please get a tag for Sri Lanka?

Tags: support, tags

Sri Lanka, officially known as [The Democratic Socialist Republic of Sri Lanka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Lanka) is an island country located in South Asia. It lies in the Indian Ocean near the equator, southwest of the Bay of Bengal, and southeast of the Arabian Sea. It is separated from the Indian subcontinent by the Gulf of Mannar and the Palk Strait. Sri Jayawardhanapura Kotte is its legislative capital. It has a rich history of over 3000 recorded years, and has been a geographically significant point in trade affairs for many years.

When I searched with the phrase Sri Lanka, I got 47 results, which I believe is proof that there's enough discussion for this tag to be created. I tried to add the tag in one of those questions, but it notified me that I had to have at least 150 of reputation to carry out that action.

Answer (score 4):

I did a similar search, and came up with [45 hits](https://history.stackexchange.com/search?q=sri%20lanka) on the History site for "Sri Lanka"

Most of the hits were in *answers*. Answers of course don't have tags, and many of them were to questions *also* on the list, so they were effectively double (or more) hits for the same question.

Even in the questions, the vast majority of the hits weren't really central to the question. For instance, one hit was in [Why is the island of Java so populated?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/59624/why-is-the-island-of-java-so-populated). Anyone clicking on that question in hopes of learning something about Sri Lankan history would be quite disappointed.

Actually looking through the 44 hits, I found the following open questions that such a [sri-lanka](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sri-lanka) tag could reasonably be applied to:

- [Is the Sri Lankan Civil War really over?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/5739/is-the-sri-lankan-civil-war-really-over)

There were however two closed questions that it could also be reasonably applied to. I won't bother linking those, because they aren't active questions on the site.

Tags of course are used for organizing the site. I don't see it being particularly helpful in organizing things to create a tag that at present will be used by all of *one* open question.

Sri Lankan history is of course a worthy subject of study. But it looks like the first thing that needs to happen here is that we need several more good questions on that topic.

Comment: @Sandun Hint, hint.